# Image extends height of flex parent, but behaves with a weird hack in chrome and safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an `image` in a flex container (let's call it `child`).
The container itself has `flex: 1` because it also belongs to a flex `parent` with `flex-direction: column` and `child` behaves as expected (takes 100% height of parent) before introducing the image situation.

On adding an image to `child`, the image extends `child` to accommodate its height, effectively `child` pushing `parent`.

Using `object-fit: cover` on the image could not help in this situation!

Looks like this is normal behaviour in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Here's the weird part tho: adding a `height` property to `child` fixes the issue on Chrome and Safari but not Firefox. This height's value doesn't matter much as long as it's not greater than the computed height of `child` - `child` is contained to `100% height` of `parent` together with the image - even if the height value of `child` is set to `1px`. Surprisingly `height: 100%` on `child` doesn't produce the same behaviour.

Any ideas around this will be much appreciated. My goal is to make the `image` always take up `100% of child` - regardless of the width of the viewport.

Here's some code for illustration

```css
#parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#child {
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
  /* the weird hack for chrome and safari - ff ignores it */
}

#child img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1005/400/1000.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I also added some images for more context. These are crops of the entire page. The first image is from a smaller viewport (width shared with devtools) and the second from the entire page (devtools hidden). The second image shows that the `image` has extended `child` to eventually push the container with a green background beyond the fold - causing a scrollbar to appear.

`child` is the image wrapper, and `parent` is the component with a white background and some padding. You realize `parent` has a sibling (green background) and their parent (container with a green border and border radius) has a `display: grid` and `grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;`.

It should also be noted that the most top-level element has a height of `100vh` and all its children are rendered within that. Essentially there should not be a scrollbar.

I hope you get the idea.

[image: small viewport (width shared with devtools)]

[image: full viewport (devtools hidden)]

Comment: try `min-height:0` for child

Comment: No effect @TemaniAfif. Why do you think that would work tho? 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/8620333

Comment: There's truth in that link @TemaniAfif. Apparently `min-height: 0` works on `grid` containers as well. However, I noticed it's supposed to be applied onto the `top-level` parent and also automatically truncates anything that overflows - as long as the full height of the image has been accommodated.

Comment: That behaviour is not desirable in my situation. The `image` should behave itself.

Comment: Do you really need an <img>? Sounds like what you wish to achieve ("to make the image always take up 100% of child - regardless of the width of the viewport")  could be made setting a background-image to that #child instead, something like `background: url('imageURL') center / auto 100% no-repeat`

Comment: Yeah, I do @Kaiido.
I didn't mention I'm using `React` to render a `scrollable` list/component (`child` in our context) of images, by passing the `url` as a `prop` to `src`. I may have to share more context for the problem to be better understood. Let me prep some screenshots.

Comment: Looks like everyone is shying away...

Comment: I will repeat my first comment: considering the code you shared `min-height: 0` fixes your issue. Replace height:1px with it on the snippet your shared and it will work

Comment: fro cross browser compatibility you can use background image instead of image tag. Support for  background image is found pretty good.

Comment: have you tried to give the child instead of 1px to inherit

Comment: Will the images always be the same size and aspect ratio?

Comment: Did you try setting 100% height to the child.
https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/MWwmZyX

Comment: It's not that the `image` is not *behav[ing] itself`. As the link provided by @TemaniAfif says, you're encountering a behaviour related to the default minimum size of flex items, not the image itself.

Comment: @greg yeah, all the images shall be identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to do?
You can also see it here: https://codepen.io/teanbiscuits/pen/GRJmPgo

```css
#parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  border:2px solid green;
  border-radius:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#child {
  position:relative;
}

#child img {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#text {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1005/400/1000.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    <h2>some title here</h2>
    <p>Some description here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you won the bounty! I love the way you approached this - making the image behave, using `absolute` positioning.

Comment: Thanks! It's an approach I use often. Depending on how you want the image to appear and if it's a product image or not you can change "object-fit: contain;" to "object-fit: cover;"

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Just select preferred object-fit.

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#parent {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#child {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#child img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1005/400/1000.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    <h2>Some title here</h2>
    <p>Some description here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```